# Echo query to table - prints every column value twice

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just starting PHP development.  I'm trying to print a daily phone report on our webserver.  The connection is established successfully, the query runs, and it prints the table, but for some reasons I can't seem to get, it prints the value of every column twice in a row.  So, phone agent John Smith is printed as

John John Smith Smith

The table is formatted.  It prints without raising errors - but the table is twice as wide as it should be because every  is printed twice.

Also, I know mysqli and PDO are preferrable to the commands I'm using here.  This is the way my textbook gives examples - I'll switch when I get more comfortable with web development.  For now even the simple things are throwing me.

If anyone can identify the problem I'd be grateful.

```
if (!($connection = mysql_connect($server,$userName,$password))) die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db($databaseName, $connection);
$myQuery = "Select (a few fields here) 
From 
callreport inner join employees on callreport .`phonenum` = employees.extension
where 
date= 20130807";
if(!($result = mysql_query($myQuery,$connection))) showerror();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $attribute){
        echo "<td>{$attribute}</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "
        </table>
    </body>
</html>";
```

Comment: What are the results of your MySQL query if run in a MySQL client rather than PHP?

Comment: you need to specify what `(a few fields here)` actually is

Comment: The fields are the time values, numbers, and names, they're metrics for a day's worth of phone calls. It pulls the name of the agent from the employee table based on their phone number, and then all the other metrics for that agent for that day from the phone report table.  Edit - Running in the the query window of phpbb it seems to object to their not being a 'Unique Column`.  I'll try including the autonumber id and see if that fixes it -

Comment: Did you try running the query on PhpMyadmin? Does it return each row twice?
Can you try Select Distinct(stuff)?

Comment: On select distinct, I did try that.  The problem is the rows are distinct, but the columns are duplicated.  For some reason phpmyadmin would only say "This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."  I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array()` returns a row from table in both ways - as a numeric and assoc indexed array:

```
$row['name']='John';
$row[0]='John';
$row['surname']='Smith';
$row[1]='Smith';
```

replace this function to `mysql_fetch_assoc()` (returns only array with associative keys) or `mysql_fetch_row()` (returns only array with numeric keys). In both cases your script will work as you predict.

Comment: Instantly fixed. Thanks, I'll do some more reading on the differences between fetch_array, assoc and row.  I appreciate it.